# Prevent horizontal text stretch in part of text

Tags: pdftex

I have a situation where I've defined a custom environment. The environment always starts with "Property #" then some text describing the property. However, due to pdfLaTeX's automatic formatting, sometimes the number is stretched along with the text following the "Property #" heading (see MWE below).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Creating a counter for the Property environment
\newcounter{ctrProperty}
% Defining a custom Property environment
\newenvironment{myProperty}{
   \refstepcounter{ctrProperty}
   \textbf{Property \thectrProperty}
   \itshape
}{\par}

\hyphenation{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\begin{document}
\begin{myProperty}
A little bit of text.
\end{myProperty}

\begin{myProperty}
More text that causes a stretch because it ends in a word supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{myProperty}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

As you can see the 2 is slightly misaligned from the 1 in the preceding property, whereas I would prefer to have the same spacing between them and their corresponding "Property". It would also be nice if the 'A' and the 'M' were aligned, but maybe that's better as a separate question.

How can I prevent LaTeX from stretching the heading? Does a command along the lines of `\nostretch{\textbf{Property \thectrProperty}}` exist?

Comment: You could add `\raggedright` as part of the environment: `\newenvironment{myProperty}{
   \refstepcounter{ctrProperty}
   \textbf{Property \thectrProperty}
   \itshape\raggedright
}{\par}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I keep the bolded property label from stretching by putting it in an `\mbox`, **including the following blank space(s)**.  Then, I invoke `\ignorespaces` after `\itshape` to squeeze out that extra liberty that LaTeX was taking in adding a space.  I make sure lines of the environment definition end in `%` to fend off extra, unwanted, space tokens.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Creating a counter for the Property environment
\newcounter{ctrProperty}
% Defining a custom Property environment
\newenvironment{myProperty}{%
   \refstepcounter{ctrProperty}%
   \mbox{\textbf{Property \thectrProperty} ~}%
   \itshape\ignorespaces%
}{\par}

\hyphenation{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\begin{document}
\begin{myProperty}
A little bit of text.
\end{myProperty}

\begin{myProperty}
 \sloppy More text that causes a stretch because it ends in a word supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{myProperty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a differnt approach, as I mentioned in a comment, one could alternatively typeset the text in `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 3):

The simple space you insert gets interpreted by TeX as a normal space, ie it has a definite amount of stretchability and shrinkability (alongside its natural width). You could try and insert manually a `hspace` amount; I opted for `0.4em` but you can choose which one looks the best for you ie:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Creating a counter for the Property environment
\newcounter{ctrProperty}
% Defining a custom Property environment
\newenvironment{myProperty}{%
   \refstepcounter{ctrProperty}%
   \textbf{Property\hspace{.4em}\thectrProperty }\itshape%
}{\par}

\hyphenation{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\begin{document}
\begin{myProperty}
A little bit of text.
\end{myProperty}

\begin{myProperty}
More text that causes a bit of a stretch because it ends in a word supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{myProperty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to @egreg for busting some spurious spaces

Comment: Spurious spaces alert!

Comment: @egreg yup I noticed, I just forgot to post the correct version. Do I think is fine now…

Comment: I count three of them. The space before `\itshape` should go before `}` instead, but you need to remove the three spurious spaces. Sorry, but Steven's answer is good and yours isn't.

Comment: @egreg ok, thank you, I removed the ones I forgot and did as suggested. I agree that Steven's answer is better

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using `enumitem` and the enumerate environment for this, instead? Then you're guaranteed to have proper spacings for the labels. And the item body starts from the same line (the 'A' and 'M' as in your question).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % not required in main file
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\hyphenation{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\newlist{myProperty}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myProperty]{before=\itshape,label=Property \arabic*, font=\normalfont\textbf, noitemsep, wide, resume}

\begin{document}
\begin{myProperty}
    \item A little bit of text.
    \item More text that no longer causes a stretch because it ends in a word supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{myProperty}

Then some intermediate text.

\begin{myProperty}
    \item A little bit of text.
    \item More text that no longer causes a stretch because it ends in a word supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{myProperty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems more natural, semantically, to define your `Property` environment as a theorem environment, with a relevant theorem style, which is easy to define with `thmtools`. For the stretching problem, define hyphenation points for the long words LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove=0pt,
spacebelow=0pt,
headfont=\bfseries,
bodyfont=\itshape,
headpunct=,
postheadspace=0.6em]{myplain}

\declaretheorem[style=myplain]{Property}

\hyphenation{super-cali-fragi-listic-expiali-docious}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{Property}
  A little bit of text.
\end{Property}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{Property}
  More text that causes a stretch because it ends in a word supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{Property}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]